# Search Controller is not showing up in TableView Controller

Tags: iphone, search, controller, tableview

I draged and dropped Search Display Controller onto my TableView Controller. When I push that TableView controller from RootView controller, Search Bar is not showing up on the top of the TableView. I used the same technique for the rootview controller and I could see SearchBar on the top of my TableView.

What could possibly cause that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the same problem, but I have asked a similar question before, perhaps that can help you.

[How do I add an UIView above a TableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265029/how-do-i-add-an-uiview-above-a-tableviewcontroller)

Cheers 
/Jimmy